# Visual select method

Tags: php, vim

Let's say I have this method in my file

```
public function handleBatch(array $records)
    {
        $messages = array();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            if ($record['level'] < $this->level) {
                continue;
            }
            $messages[] = $this->processRecord($record);
        }

        if (!empty($messages)) {
            $messages = $this->getFormatter()->formatBatch($messages);
            self::$json['rows'] = array_merge(self::$json['rows'], $messages);
            $this->send();
        }
    }
```

How to visual select the method from the public keyword to the last } ?
I have tried v2aBV but doesn't work for me.

Comment: You seem to know the relevant motions already; what exactly "doesn't work" for you?!

Comment: It select the content between the {} but not public function handleBatch(array $records)

Answer (score 1):

You already know the `aB` / `a{` text object. With `[m`, you can go to the start of a method (in a curly-braces language); that should avoid using large counts when inside a deeply nested structure.

When you're in a visual selection and need to extend the "other side", `o` gets you there. **This `o` move allows you to include the preceding function definition, e.g. with `k`.**

#### Alternative approach

I usually tackle the problem of selecting / moving an entire method with another feature: folding. With the proper setup (`:setlocal foldmethod=syntax` is enough when the syntax supplies fold definitions), all methods are folded together, and one can quickly select one with `V`, or just directly `dd` / `p` it.

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is on the `*f*unction`, you could try to press:

```
v]m%
```

Comment: This work fine, but how to achieve the same effect if the cursor is in the method body?

Answer (score 1):

One could jump to the definition, start visual mode, jump to the opening bracket, then to the closing bracket and switch to visual-line mode:

```
[[v]m%V
```

That's still a lot of typing, though, but it's easy to turn it into a crude mapping:

```
nmap vaf [[v]m%V
```

Note that [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) does exactly what you want with `vai` in a certainly smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are with the cursor **before** the method definition, should be used the following command:

`]]v]m%`

If you are with the cursor **after** the method definition - this goes for the cursor in the body of the method as well - you should use the following command:

`[[v]m%`

**This will make it selected the entire definition of your method and your body.**

If you want to leave the word "public" out of the selection shall be used the following command

1 - If the cursor is before the method definition:

`]]wv]m%`

2 - If the cursor is after the method definition:

`[[wv]m%`